# Abstract base class definition

Tags: c++

Can this be a definition of an abstract base class : "contains only pure virtual methods and often serves as an interface specification for derived classes"

or can the abstract base class also contain other methods(also virtual)

Comment: "contains at least one pure virtual method" would be a better definition.

Comment: A class is abstract if it contains at least one pure virtual method. It can contain other methods - pure virtual, virtual, and/or non-virtual.

Comment: Classes which are only pure virtual (no other methods or data members) are normally called interfaces. An abstract class is an interface that can have regular functions as well. Both types cannot be instantiated due to pure virtual functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition from the C++ standard (§10.4, Abstract Classes, emphasis mine):

> An *abstract class* is a class that can be used only as a base class of some other class; no objects of an abstract
>   class can be created except as subobjects of a class derived from it. A class is abstract if it has **at least
>   one** *pure virtual function*. *[ Note:* Such a function might be inherited: see below. *—end note ]*
>
> ```
> class point { / ... / };
> class shape { // abstract class
>     point center;
> public:
>     point where() { return center; }
>     void move(point p) { center=p; draw(); }
>     virtual void rotate(int) = 0; // pure virtual
>     virtual void draw() = 0; // pure virtual
> };
> ```

In the example, `shape` contains two pure virtual methods (which makes it an abstract class), but also contains two non-virtual methods. That is OK. So your original definition that an abstract class contains *only* pure virtual functions is too constricting. Just having at least one such is sufficient.

Comment: thanks  for that...i read the definition somewhere and got really confused..!!

Comment: @KaushikReddy There are some definitions like this out there: They originate from people who think more about programming than doing it themselves. For an abstract thinking academic an abstract class is not truly abstract unless there is no non-abstract part to it (I should know, I'm an academic... ;-) ) But if you ask about C++, the definition of the language standard is normative.